# Mock all interfaces from assembly using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

Is it possible to mock all interfaces from an assembly using Moq?

Here's what I'm trying to do but it seems that there is no way to create a mock without a generic parameter.

```
var mocks = new List<Mock>();
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Project.Core");
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsInterface))
{            
    mocks.Add(new Mock(type)); // Doesn't work. Has to be new Mock<T>().
}
```

Comment: It's unclear why you want to do this in the first place, but you can always create the mocks via reflection.

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do?